# Restate(override) css-transition after it has already triggered

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is it possible to restate(override) css-transition after it has already triggered?

It seems down right impossible to override `transition-delay` after the css-transition has already taking effect.
(Especially considering the possible case when delay duration might have past already, delay value gets shortened and so on.)
However I failed to find concrete explanation.

I suppose css-transition has to be instructed at before or the exact same time when the change of target property (`background-color` in this case) is instructed?

(Sorry I had to edit numerous times to narrow down my question. If anyone wonder why I need such thing, I explained a mechanism I want below. It's already in simplified of my project.)

---

What I'm trying to do is

- Before jQuery 'load' event, `background-color: transparent` is applied.
- Then on jQuery 'load' event, apply `background-color: red`
  (which is determined by css with class name `loaded` added by jQuery).
- On the otherhand, `transition-delay` is determined separately by its class name which is provided by jQuery.

### Clarification

Just to differentiate from other similar questions..

1. I **only** need `transition-delay` to be override conditionally.
   Although interestingly, it would succeed when `background-color` is changed alongside.
2. Overriding happens conditionally, i.e: CSSOM remains constant but DOM's class name might change after its initial state. (To be specific to this case, class is added when the button is pressed.)
   Override succeeds while DOM stays constant, but that's not what I want.

---

[Here's fiddle to illustrate the situation](https://jsfiddle.net/alexklaus80/ua18txan/19/)

**HTML**

```html
<div>
<!-- class name "loaded" will be given after load event. -->
  <p class="delay delay-1s">
  <!-- class name 'delay-1s' will be replaced with 'delay-5s' with button -->
    This will be turning into red after loaded in..<br>
    1.) 1 seconds without button or<br>
    2.) 5 second with button
  </p>
</div>

<button id="change-delay">Change delay to 5s</button>
```

**CSS**

```css
/* Make P from transparent to red when loaded */
div p {
  background-color: transparent;
}
div.loaded p {
  background-color: red;
}

.delay.delay-1s {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
.delay.delay-5s {
  transition-delay: 5s;
}
```

**Javascript**

```javascript
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('div').addClass('loaded');
});
$('button#change-delay').click(function() {
    $('.delay').removeClass('delay-1s').addClass('delay-5s');
});
```

I tested this on Chrome/Firefox updated to this day (Sep 2017), but both returned the same result.

---

edit1:
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the time to provide class name.
If I add the class `btn-pressed` in HTML, i.e hardcode them on the document, override works as intended. Although, it wouldn't happen exclusively when the class is modified.

edit2:
Added clarification.

edit3:
Narrowed down question.

edit4:
adding timelapse of event happening on code:

1. Loads document.
   `P` gets `background-color: transparent` and `transition-delay: 1s;`
2. Loading is done, adding class 'loaded' to `DIV`,
   `P` gets `background-color: red`  **and fires css-transition**
3. `BUTTON` gets clicked*, adding class 'btn-pressed' to `DIV`.
   `P` gets `transition-delay: 5s;` assigned, overrides CSSOM; however, **since css-transition from 2. is already in action, it doesn't take effect**.

*Surely, if `BUTTON` has clicked before loading completed, it will take effect.

I was too lazy to read W3C documents but maybe that's what I should do in spare time..

Comment: I think the css seletor is the cause of the problem. Also put your jquery code.

Comment: @RajendranNadar Thanks, I have put script too. Later I hard-coded HTML with classname for overriding the property and it worked. However I don't know how to improve selector.

Comment: I think I don't completely understand the problem, but anyway, check this Fiddle based on the one you have posted: [https://jsfiddle.net/ua18txan/9/](https://jsfiddle.net/ua18txan/9/)

Comment: @MiguelMorera In very short, I want to "change transition-delay after the button is clicked". Thanks for the edit, but I'm sorry I couldn't see any change from your edit.

Comment: I tried to do it several ways, but looks it is impossible, once assigned it simply won't change.

Comment: @skobaljic Thanks a lot for try! I think it can't restate once css-transition has fired, which in this case it is. I'm thinking about changing a question to narrow down about that.

Answer (score 0):

Html code here

```
<div class="bg">
   <p>test here</p>
</div>
<button class="btn">Activate</button>
```

Css code here

```
.bg {
   min-height: 200px;
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Js code here

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var delay = 5000;
    If ( $('.bg').hasClass('pressed') ) {
        delay = 2000; //set delay to 2 sec,
    }

    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        $('.bg').addClass('pressed');
    });

    $('.bg').animate({
        'background-color': 'red'
    }, delay);
});
```

I assume that you have jquery. If any issue plz let me know by putting a comment below.

I hope this is what you need.

Note - Make few changes as per you needs like class name and events.

Comment: Thanks man, I was avoiding javascript animate but I should've checked that. Although, javascript animate seems not to override the one already triggered also. On the side note, I just noticed click event should've been assigned before load event ;)

Comment: Just to demonstrate what I wanted to do and how I interpreted your suggestion, if you were interested please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/alexklaus80/ua18txan/15/

Comment: Oh my bad the click event should be out side the load event.